# Proper way to include multiple forms in a single table

Tags: html

Is there a correct way to include multiple forms in a single table?

For example, I have 8 rows, four of them correspond to a single table, the other four correspond to a second. What would be the best way to do this? I know putting a  table between TRs is invalid.

Comment: I'm not following you; your question talks about forms, but your example is just about multiple tables.  Can you flesh out your example?

Comment: Do you mean "four of them correspond to a single *form*"? What is the difference between those 2 forms?

Comment: question needs to ensure that the terms `form`, `table` are not mixed up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is a standard way to do this. (which sucks)

You'll have to do something like give all the form elements in a row a prefix to indicate which row they are in, then detect which button was pressed. On the server you can then discard all the values that you aren't interested in.

edit: The information (name and value) of the buttons not pressed won't be submitted)

(Alternatively, if you use javascript you should be able to make work around to collect all the values from that row's inputs when the button is pressed.)

Answer (score 5):

I think I found the solution for your problem, since I found myself on the same situation. Here is an example of what I did.

```
<form id="uno" name="uno" action="somescript.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" id="myhidden" value="1">
</form>
<form id="dos" name="dos" action="anotherscript.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" id="myhidden" value="2">
</form>

<table id="uniqueTable">
<tr>
<td><input form="uno" type="text" id="x_value" name="x_value" value="0.00"></td>
<td><input form="dos" type="text" id="x_anothervalue" name="x_anothervalue" value="0.00"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

In this way, although there is only one table each of your inputs will belong to the form stated with the `form="formName"`

Hope it helps someone
- anakin

Comment: It is a correct answer, but currently it is not supported by IE: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_form.asp

Comment: Who uses IE anyway? :P