# form created from ajax javascript but action not working

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have created a table from data returned as json from a php file using ajax.

This table contains a form of two columns of each row which again calls a php file in action. this form action is not working.

```
function get_data() {

    var compnm=$('#compnm').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "mchdet.php", // Name of the php files
        data: {
            compnm:compnm
        },
        dataType:'json',
        success: function(jsn)
        {

            var html = "",val="";
            var html =  '<thead>'+
            '<tr>'+
            '<th><strong>S.No.</strong></th>'+
            '<th><strong>Company</strong></th>'+
            '</tr>'+
            '</thead>'+
                '<tbody>';

                $.each(jsn, function(index) 
                {
                    console.log(jsn[index].COMPNM);
                    var a = index + 1;
                    html = html + '<tr> <td align="center"> '+a+'</td> '+
                    '<td align="center">'+jsn[index].COMPNM+'</td>'+
                    '<form action="edtmch.php" method = "POST" onsubmit="alert("Called onsubmit");">'+
                    '<td>'+
                    '   <input type="radio" name ="del" id="del" value = "shift">Shift<br/>'+
                    '   <input type="radio" name ="del" id="del" value = "expire">Expire'+
                    '</td>'+
                    '<td> '+
                    '   <input type="hidden" name = "id" id="id" value = '+jsn[index].ID+'</input>'+
                    '   <input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "Edit" ></input>'+
                    '</td>'+
                '</form>'+
                '</tr>';
        });
        html = html + '</tbody></table>';
            $("#get_data").html(html);

        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

html used to display table

```
<div id="get_data"></div>
```

The data displays perfectly fine but the issue is form action even on submit alert also not shown not working

Comment: IDs are supposed to be unique, you shouldn't use the same ID in each form.

Comment: You have a typo: `missing `>` in `<input type="hidden" name = "id" id="id" value = '+jsn[index].ID+'</input>'`. Also, there's no such thing as `</input>`, input tags are self-closing.

Comment: You're generating invalid HTML. You can't have `<form>...</form>` around `<td>` elements. The children of `<tr>` have to be `<td>`.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4168439/proper-way-to-include-multiple-forms-in-a-single-table

Comment: What **exactly** do you mean by "not working"? What have you tried to debug that?

Comment: when i created this table by using simple html and php its form action was working fine but when i created it using ajax <form action="edtmch.php" method = "POST" onsubmit="alert("Called onsubmit");"> stopped working